# Create Collection fails in SolrCloud

Tags: solr, hdfs, apache-zookeeper, solrcloud

I am trying to create a collection in solrcloud that is on top of hadoop cluster. 
We have three node zk ensemble, chosen hdfs for data/index storage.

I went through the documentation available, and started solr on 4 data nodes on my cluster (solr 4.10.2).

```
java -DzkHost=zk1:2181,zk2:2181,zk3:2181 -Dsolr.directoryFactory=HdfsDirectoryFactory -Dsolr.lock.type=hdfs -Dsolr.hdfs.home=hdfs://nn:8020/solr -Dsolr.hdfs.confdir=/etc/hadoop/conf -jar "$SOLR_HOME"/example/start.jar >> "$SOLR_HOME"/logs/solr.out 2>&1 &
```

Now, the solrCloud documentation says that we need to run below steps in that order.

Upconfig

```
"$SOLR_HOME"/example/scripts/cloud-scripts/zkcli.sh -cmd upconfig -zkhost zk1:2181,zk:2181,zk3:2181 -confdir "$SOLR_HOME"/example/solr/TestCol/conf -confname TEST_CONF;
```

LinkConfig

```
"$SOLR_HOME"/example/scripts/cloud-scripts/zkcli.sh -cmd linkconfig -zkhost zk1:2181,zk2:2181,zk3:2181 -collection TEST_COL -confname TEST_CONF;
```

createCollection

```
curl 'http://tlccmrhdd01:8983/solr/admin/collections?action=CREATE&name=TEST_COL&numShards=4&replicationFactor=2&maxShardsPerNode=2&createNodeSet=node1:8983_solr,node2:8983_solr,node3:8983_solr,node4:8983_solr'
```

The upconfig, and linkconfig steps went through fine, but the createCollection step fails with below stack trace:

```
Collection: TEST_COL operation: createcollection failed:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.OverseerCollectionProcessor.createCollection(OverseerCollectionProcessor.java:2258)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.OverseerCollectionProcessor.processMessage(OverseerCollectionProcessor.java:551)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.OverseerCollectionProcessor$Runner.run(OverseerCollectionProcessor.java:2629)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$NodeExistsException: KeeperErrorCode = NodeExists for /collections/TEST_COL
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:119)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:51)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.create(ZooKeeper.java:783)
    at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.SolrZkClient$11.execute(SolrZkClient.java:462)
    at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ZkCmdExecutor.retryOperation(ZkCmdExecutor.java:74)
    at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.SolrZkClient.makePath(SolrZkClient.java:459)
    at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.SolrZkClient.makePath(SolrZkClient.java:416)
    at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.SolrZkClient.makePath(SolrZkClient.java:403)
    at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.SolrZkClient.makePath(SolrZkClient.java:390)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.OverseerCollectionProcessor.createConfNode(OverseerCollectionProcessor.java:2420)
    at org.apache.solr.cloud.OverseerCollectionProcessor.createCollection(OverseerCollectionProcessor.java:2164)


null:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException
    at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CollectionsHandler.handleResponse(CollectionsHandler.java:364)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CollectionsHandler.handleResponse(CollectionsHandler.java:320)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CollectionsHandler.handleCreateAction(CollectionsHandler.java:486)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CollectionsHandler.handleRequestBody(CollectionsHandler.java:148)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:135)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.handleAdminRequest(SolrDispatchFilter.java:729)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:267)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:207)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1419)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:455)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:557)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1075)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:384)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1009)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:368)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:489)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handleRequest(BlockingHttpConnection.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:942)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1004)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:640)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handle(BlockingHttpConnection.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio.SocketConnector$ConnectorEndPoint.run(SocketConnector.java:264)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Comment: Please help me to figure out what am I missing here. I dont have any other log apart from what I pasted here.

Comment: The problem here is that the zkCli shows the collection name under /collections, but the solr Web UI says "no cores available"

Comment: Hi, any luck om this? I am as well facing same issue when setting up SolrCloud on Hadoop. I am seeing the NodeExistsException when trying to create the collection. Let me know if you had found a way to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Just run into the same issue, here's what solved it:

(1) issue the upconfig command, which will upload the solr conf to zk.

(2) issue create collection command but make sure to add "&collection.configName=TEST_CONF" (this will create the collection and use the configuration files you've just uploaded).

Do NOT use the linkconfig command as it causes the "NodeExists" exception.